# .NET 5 conversion from .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am converting an application from Webforms to .NET Core 3.1, which should be done by the end of the year.

The application must be updated and maintained over time. I saw that in November Microsoft will publish .NET 5, but it will be a non-LTS version (without long support).

Is is better to convert now, or should I wait for .NET 6 (LTS version) which is scheduled to be released in 2021?

Comment: Today I've migrated our company's Asp Net Core 3.1 (quite big and complicated web-app) to DotNet 5 almost without any problems - it took me 10 minutes.

Comment: @sabiland did you run into any issues around deprecations?  The upgrade was easy except for what to do about deprecations on EF like `.Distinct()` on our queries.

Answer (score 2):

If the application is ported to .NET Core 3.1, you can move to .NET 5 with only minor changes.

So continue your migration to .NET 3.1, which is the base of .NET 5.

Have a look at the Preview 6 [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-6/).